# How can I repartitioning Ubuntu using "unallocated" spaces at random parts of my hard drive?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have this unallocated space before my root partition and GParted doesn't let me add it to my Ubuntu partitions. I am running Ubuntu from a USB drive. While it lets me add it my Windows partitions. What can I do to increase my partition size (selected in the picture)? 
[GParted Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLJSb.png)

Comment: In order to give you good advice, I need to ask a few questions first. Windows has a lot of disk space available. Do you use Windows? If so, how much of the time? Why do you have 2 EXT4 partitions, and 2 linux-swap partitions? How much RAM do you have installed? Did you reinstall Ubuntu a second time? Cheers, Al

Comment: Also... is sda6 your / root partition, and sda7 your /home partition? Please edit your question to include the output of `df`, and `sudo fdisk -l` (lower case L), and `cat /etc/fstab`. Cheers, Al

Comment: Heynnema,
I want to use the free space I have on Windows and I use it once a week or so. One ext4 is for root files (sda6) and the other for home files (sda7).
I have 4GB of RAM and I created a linux-swap partition because I was experimenting. I think I deleted it.

Comment: Without reducing the Windows partition, the best that we'll be able to do is add ~15GB to /root, and ~15GB to /home. Windows is about 75% free space. Please advise. Cheers, Al

Comment: Also, to reach me, make sure to add @heynnema to the beginning of your comments. Cheers, Al

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. First, I had to delete the extra linux-swap. Then open up some space from my Windows partition. But GParted wouldn't let me adjust the partition. Then I had to restart and boot from the USB again. This time, GParted allowed me to move them around. Thank you all for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create partition table at first and then mount the filesystem to the OS.
If you mean that you want to shrink your root partition you should use something like `resize2fs` utility.
You can do the same with GParted while booting from liveCD.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)